# Regular carburettor vs chainsaw carburettor

Tags: carburetor

Could someone explain their differences? By regular carburettor i mean the one which you usually find on motorbikes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are different because chainsaw engines and carbs are used at much more extreme angles than car engines.

Unless you want to do vertical in your car.

There is plenty of info about both types of carbs available so I won’t add that info here.

Comment: And chainsaw carbs "suck" the fuel supply where motorbikes are normally gravity feed.